# dynamic checkbox creation to run function onclick

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is used to create a checkbox for each item in an array.

The problem I'm having is when trying to create a function when it is clicked, this function also needs to be created dynamically from the items in the array but only seems to get the first item.

```
function createCheckboxes(markerGroups) {

    var container = document.getElementById('panel');

    for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups.length; i++) {

        var dataTypeId1 = markerGroups[i];
        console.log(dataTypeId1);

        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.name = "chk" + markerGroups[i].dataTypeId;
        checkbox.value = "value";
        checkbox.id = "chk" + markerGroups[i].dataTypeId;

        checkbox.onclick = function () {

            console.log(dataTypeId1);

        };

        checkbox.checked = true;

        var label = document.createElement('label')
        label.htmlFor = "chk" + markerGroups[i].dataTypeId;
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(markerGroups[i].dataTypeName));

        container.appendChild(checkbox);
        container.appendChild(label);

    }

}
```

In the code above at 2 points I write to the log. The first time produces a list of IDs as expected e.g.

```
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
```

The onclick function needs to get the current ID in the array but always returns the first item/ID '1001' no matter which checkbox I click on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the onclick function to this

```
checkbox.onclick = (function(dataType) {
    return function () {
        console.log(dataType);
    };
}(dataTypeId1))
```

read on [Javascript Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) to understand more

Comment: That works great but no idea how...thanks for the link to the info I'll have a read.